# Django Query Result Structure

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to Django and have been trying to get it to structure a query result in a certain way. After a few hours of trying, I'm hoping someone can show me how to improve the desired result.

In this simplified example, a word is created, users submit definitions for that word, and vote on each definition (funniest, saddest, wtf, etc.):

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Word(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    word = models.CharField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

class Definition(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    definition = models.CharField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

class Vote_category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField()

class Vote_history(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    definition = models.ForeignKey(Definition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    vote = models.ForeignKey(Vote_category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Expected Query Result Structure**

```
word: 'hello',
definitions: {
    {
        user: 'alice',
        definition: 'an expression of greeting',
        votes: {
            funny: 3,
            sad: 1,
            wtf: 7
        },
        votes_total: 11
    },
    etc...
}
```

**Current Query**

Get the word that was created on a specific date. Then get all its definitions:

```
Word.objects.filter(timestamp__date=datetime.date(2017, 2, 5)).values('definition__definition')
```

**Current Result**

```
<QuerySet [{'definition__definition': 'an expression of greeting'}, {'definition__definition': 'blah blah blah'}]>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: This isn't a structure you'd get from a query. You would need to make your query to get the data, then use Python to process it into the form you want.

Comment: I think your need is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json